# symmetric equation module p

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

prove the equation 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_{\frac{p-1}{2}}\overset{p}{\equiv} x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_{\frac{p-1}{2}}^2\overset{p}{\equiv}...\overset{p}{\equiv}x_1^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+x_2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+...+x_{\frac{p-1}{2}}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$$
has no nontrivial solution.

I am interested in different solutions for this problem and possibly better bound than $\frac{p-1}{2}$.

Comment: Can you confirm that $p$ is a prime?

Comment: Yes p is a prime number